# c# Server Error in '/WEBSITE' Application.Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql, sql-insert

i got this error whenever  trying to insert data  from the form into the database.
Server Error in '/WEBSITE' Application.Incorrect syntax near '='.
This is my code below.

```
 private void insertMemberRecord(string name, string contact, string dob, string gender, int age, string country, string email, string add, string user, string pw, string resume)
{
    string strconnectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection myconnect = new SqlConnection(strconnectionstring);
    string strcommandtext = "INSERT Member(MemberName,MemberContact,MemberDOB,MemberGender,MemberAge,MemberCountry,MemberEmail,MemberAddress,MemberUserName,MemberPw,MemberResume) ";

    strcommandtext += " Values(@memname,@memcontact,@memdob,@memgender,@memage,@memcountry,@mememail,@memadd,@memuser,@mempw,@memresume)";


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strconnectionstring, myconnect);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memname",name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memcontact", contact);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memdob", dob);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memgender", gender);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memage", age);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memcountry", country);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mememail", email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memadd", add);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memuser", user);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memresume", resume);

    myconnect.Open();

    int result =cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if(result>0)
    {
        lblerr.Text ="Record Inserted";
    }
    else
    {
        lblerr.Text ="Register Failed";
    }
    myconnect.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you know what line the error is occurring on?  Try to get a stack trace so you can get more information.

Comment: I can't see any way this query would throw this error since `=` does not actually appear in the command text at all. For what it's worth though, you don't add the parameter `@mempw` to the command, so that will probably generate an error.

Comment: GarethD i added @mempw and it still didnt work though.

Comment: Mark Wagoner the error is occuring on Line 65:         int result =cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

and the stack trace is the following

Comment: the entire stack trace is over the limit of word count though
this is a part of it

[SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '='.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1752722
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5294778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing your connection string into your command object instead of your query.
Try this syntax instead:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myconnect);
```

Comment: oh my god i can't believe i made such a mistake.
Thank you it works now.